# Is it possible to use image loading library with odoo mobile framework

Tags: java, android, odoo, picasso, android-glide

I am working on an app base on odoo mobile framework , I find trouble with fetching images from server (which done with base 64 encode/decode) , I am trying to involve one of the image loading library (Glide, Picasso .etc) to do the work (easier, more efficient, help me to optimize usage data/wifi ). The problem is the framework use "authentication" in all its requests , and without this authentication Glide couldn't upload images from server. Any one have an idea how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can display image(attachment) using any lazy loading library using below syntax for URL for attachment using id

```
http://URL/web/content/<attachment_id>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use image by URL as below

```
http://serverurl/web/image/<odoomodelname>/<record_id>/<image_field_name>
```